# what is the system function in python

Tags: python, function

I want to play with system command in python . for example we have this function in perl : system("ls -la"); and its run ls -la what is the system function in python ? 
Thanks in Advance .

Answer (score 6):

It is [`os.system`](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.system):

```
import os
os.system('ls -la')
```

But this won't give you any output. So [`subprocess.check_output`](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output) is probably more what you want:

```
>>> import subprocess
>>> subprocess.check_output(["ls", "-l", "/dev/null"])
'crw-rw-rw- 1 root root 1, 3 Oct 18  2007 /dev/null\n'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import os
os.system("")
```

From [here](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.system)

Answer (score 1):

In the `os` module there is [`os.system()`](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.system).

But if you want to do more advanced things with subprocesses the [`subprocess`](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html) module provides a higher level interface with more possibilities that is usually preferable.